# Is an integral basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ a basis for $\mathbb{Q}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ be a integral basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, which means $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ is a basis and components of each of them are integers.
Let $b$ be an integral vector. As we know, $b$ is a linear combination of $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ over $\mathbb{R}$. But could we write $b$ as a linear combination of $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ with rational coefficients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  We know that $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\subset\mathbb{Q}^n$, and they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ and hence over $\mathbb{Q}$ as well.  But every linearly independent set of $n$ elements in an $n$-dimensional vector space is a basis, so $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ must be a basis for $\mathbb{Q}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because if we solve the linear equation system and $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, the coefficients must be rational.